# Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function - AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, dom, scope

I'm trying to execute some angular JS, via my chrome console.  (I'm adding a new controller into my DOM).

However, I'm returned the following error:
`Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function`

I've seen lots of questions, around how to run $ in my console, to run angular methods or access scope.  But I just can't seem to get $ working.

What do I need to do, to access $ in console, when using angular?

Here's the code, I'm running:

```
angular.module("app",[])
.controller('cart', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.content = {
        label: "hello, world!",
    };
});

setTimeout(() => {
  
var $html = '<div ng-controller="cart">{{content.label}}</div>';
var $root = $('[ng-app]');
console.log($root);

var inj = angular.element($root).injector();
console.log(inj);


angular.element($root).injector().invoke(function ($compile) {
    var $scope = angular.element($root).scope();
    $root.append($compile($html)($scope));
    // Finally, refresh the watch expressions in the new element
    $scope.$apply();
});


},500);
```

Comment: $ is jquery and error says that it is not defined

Comment: @PetrAveryanov Hmmm... this is an angular controller, (not JQuery), so I was wondering how I can access angular's $ in console